# jframe doesn't display correctly

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This is what happens when I run a preview of the jframe
[image: The jframe doesn't display correctly]

How am I able to solve this?
 Thanks

Comment: ` this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); `

Comment: that's "formWindowOpened" methods

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setSize(width,height)` and `setLocation(x,y)` methods to set desired size and position of your JFrame.

OR

Simply call `pack()` on your JFrame before calling `setVisible(true)` on it.

But as MadProgrammer has suggested it is always better to use some Layouts and Layout Managers.

Answer (score 0):

set size of the jframe

```
jframe.setSize(width,height);
```

Comment: Better to use appropriate layouts and pack in order to support multiple platforms, fonts, dpi and other variable rendering issues